# Dynamic Regex for min and max

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to validate an input using Regular expression

1. It should accept only digit
2. Min and max should be dynamic

Thanks for your help in advance

My code is

```
min=3, max=10
```

MyRegex is

```
/^(\d{min, max})$/
```

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: its not taking min and max as a variable instead its considering as value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a template string:

```js
let min = 2;
let max = 4;

let r = new RegExp(`^\\d{${min},${max}}$`);

[
 '2',
 '1',
 '10',
 'aos',
 '3333',
 '33',
].forEach(s => console.log("%s\t: %s", s, r.test(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template strings and RegExp constructor.

```js
const test = (str,min,max) => new RegExp(`^\\d{${min},${max}}$`).test(str)
console.log(test('1234',2,4))
```